# Proving that a definite integral is equal to zero

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I'm currently assuming that $$\int_a^b \left| f(x)-\left( \frac{1}{b-a} \int_a^b f(y) \, dy \right) \right| \, dx=0$$

$a\neq b$

How can I prove this result?

(it's been suggested that I use mean value theorem)

Comment: Please, rewrite your expression. At the moment, there are two integral signs but only one "dx". This is not correct. See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference here.

Comment: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: I've rewritten the expression based on what I was reading. Please check if it's correct.

Comment: I edited it to include the limits of integration a and b. Is this what you intended?

Comment: Any assumption on $\;f\;$ ? Differentiable, continuous...or only integrable?

Answer (score 1):

This is not true in general, and it is easy to find counterexamples (take $f(x)=x$ on $[0,1]$ for example). Moreover, if $f\in L^1([a,b])$, then
$$
0=\int_a^b\left|f(x)-\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(y)dy\right|dx=||f-c||_{L^1([a,b])},
$$
where $c:=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b f(y)dy$, and this implies that $f=c$ almost everywhere on $[a,b]$.

This shows that the functions satisfying your identity have to be constant almost everywhere!

However, your statement becomes true when you remove the absolute value...

Comment: If you take $f(x) = x$ on $[0,1]$, the integral gives $0$.

Comment: No. $\int_0^1xdx=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\int_0^1|x-\frac{1}{2}|dx=\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: This is not true. Do your integration step by step again, then you will see that your last two integrals are both $1/8$.

Comment: Yeah! You're right! I did a sign mistake in second integral. :)